# Spring REST API to play live audio

Tags: java, spring, audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I am trying to create a new Spring REST API for live Audio, Couldn't find any related articles, Please share if anyone has already worked on this.

Comment: https://twilblog.github.io/java/spring/rest/file/stream/2015/08/14/return-a-file-stream-from-spring-rest.html   try this tutorial

Comment: For live Audio?

Answer (score 2):

Try [howlerjs](https://howlerjs.com/), they have live radio demo